# Tensorflow : Enlarge images on Tensorboard embedding?

Tags: image, tensorflow, visualization, embedding, tensorboard

The images on the Tensorboard embedding visualization are fairly small. 
It's ok for MNIST, but not good for other real images.

Even when I zoom in, the image sizes are not changing. 
I tried to use larger sprite image size but it doesn't work as well.

Is there a way to make it bigger? Thanks!!

Comment: I've the similat issue, have you found solution ?